# Python: prevent deleting temp file on close

Tags: python

I need to create a temp file with some contents for test:

```py
def test_something():
  tmp_path = make_temp_file('hello\nworld')
  do_something(tmp_path)
```

but the following code I used to make the file automatically deletes the file on close:

```py
  def make_temp_file(text):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp_file:
      tmp_file.write(text.encode('utf-8'))
      tmp_file.flush()
      return tmp_file.name
```

so, in `do_something(tmp_path)` the file was not found. How can I prevent deleting the tmp file on close? I'll manually delete it after the test.

Comment: [There is a delete parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) which defaults to true.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 8):

There is a [delete parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) which defaults to true. So the code should be `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)` in the example.

Thanks to @juanpa.arrivillaga.